# Timepicker validation? JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, timepicker

I use timepicker for my start and end time. I would like to have validation on these two input fields in case if user enter wrong time format. Here is my HTML code:

```
<th>Start Time:</th>
<td>
   <input type="text" id="stime" name="stime" maxlength="10"/>
</td>
<th>End Time:</th>
<td>
   <input type="text" id="etime" name="etime" maxlength="10"/>
</td>
```

Here is my JavaScript validation code:

```
var sTime = $('#stime').val();
var eTime = $('#etime').val();
var regExp = /^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/i

if(regExp.test(sTime) == false){
    alert('Start Time is wrong');
}else if(regExp.test(eTime) == false){
    alert('End Time is wrong');
}
```

My code does not work, If I pick correct time format in my timepicker I will get alert that time is wrong. If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. My time values look like this:

```
start time: 08:00 am 
end time: 01:15 pm
```

Comment: What is "timepicker" is that a framework / api?

Comment: you should provide sTime and eTime example values. Just console them and copy paste content in question.

Comment: timepicker is a api framework.

Comment: is the string "start time: " part of the time value? @user3023588

Comment: This regex expects a 24 format of hh:mm:ss - seconds being optional.

Comment: Switch your regex pattern to /^(([0]?[1-9])|(1[0-2])):([0-5]?[0-9])\s([a|p]m)$/i as I've used here: https://regex101.com/r/wA9jK9/2 - note that I haven't exhaustively tested it, but I think it should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match the time intervals splitted in `am` and `pm` the time range will be between `00:00` and `12:59`.

So your regex will be:

```
^(?:(?:0?\d|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d)$
```

Check the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL0tQ1/5)

**Legenda**

```
^                # Start of the string
 (?:             # NCG1
   (?:           # NCG2
     0?\d        # An optional zero followed by a single number between zero and nine \d is just like [0-9]
       |         # OR
       1[0-2]    # A literal '1' followed by a single number between zero and two
    )            # CLOSE NCG2
    :            # A literal colon ':'
    [0-5]\d      # A single number from 0 to 5 followed by any digit
  )              # CLOSE NCG1
$                # End of the string
```

**Js Demo**

```js
var re = /^(?:(?:0?\d|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d)$/;

var tests = ['08:00','01:15','1:14','02:23','23:23','12:01','13:05','3:04','5:65','0:0','12:9','0:34','0:01','00:31','0:00','00:00'];
var m;

while(t = tests.pop()) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += '"' + t + '"<br/>';
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += 'Valid time? ' + ( (t.match(re)) ? '<font color="green">YES</font>' : '<font color="red">NO</font>') + '<br/><br/>';
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

**Update**: i've modified the regex to discard some values accepted before such like the weird `0:0` or `12:9` (depending on the single digit minute section), as suggested by Mic in the comment.

However the regex continues to match the minutes after midnight `00:xx` and noon `12:xx`. In the italian digital clocks this is just the way used to distinguish on the fly between zenith and nadir (i can't be sure it's universally accepted but i think it's a reasonable default).

Comment: I think this regex has some issues. It will match single-digit minutes (for example: 0:0, 12:9 are both valid). Conventionally that's not normally a representation that is used. Also, if you're using AM/PM, I wouldn't expect 0:xx to be a valid time. If you aren't using AM/PM you need to accept 13-23 hours.